# AngularJS, nested controllers from variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Generally, what I want to do, is to initialize nested `ng-controller` inside `ng-repeat` using variable.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw5tg3mp/3/)

**JS**

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('main',function($scope){
    angular.extend($scope,{
        name:'Parent Controller',
        items:[
            {name:'nested2'},
            {name:'nested1'}
            ]
    });
})
.controller('nested1',function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Name1";
})
.controller('nested2',function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Name2";
});
```

I want this:

```
<div ng-controller="main" ng-app='app'>
    Nested: {{name}}
    <div ng-controller="nested1">{{name}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="nested2">{{name}}</div>
</div>
```

to become to something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="main">
    Nested: {{name}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div ng-controller="item.name">{{name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem: it does not work this way. Neither it works any other way, that I've tried after google'ing for an hour or so.

Is there any "legal" and nice way to achieve that at all?

Comment: What do you want to do? Example your provided is wrong usage of Controller, you should supply ng-model or Service, but I guess that's just an artifact of simplification.

Comment: `ng-repeat` already creates child controllers for each iteration.

Comment: @DavidSergey, I've updated the question. What I want is ... let's say I have a collection of widgets. Each widget has a controller. I want to ng-repeat through this collection and create nested controller for each of them

Comment: @tymeJV, I want to have some complicated logic under these nested controllers, with it's scopes etc.

Comment: What kind of logic...you can already make some pretty complex things with the nested controllers as-is

Comment: @tymeJV, yes I can. I have couple of other solutions to make it work too. But my question is if it's possible to do what I ask.

Comment: I doubt it's legal / correct way of doing it - but im not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a real way,using angular features it at this point, i suppose. You could create a directive and use un-documented dynamic controller feature `controller:'@', name:'controllerName'`. But this approach will not evaluate bindings or expressions that provide the controller name. What i can think of is a hack by instantiating a controller provided and setting it to the element.

Example:-

```
.directive('dynController', function($controller){
  return {
    scope:true, //create a child scope
    link:function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var ctrl =scope.$eval(attrs.dynController); //Get the controller
      ///Instantiate and set the scope
      $controller(ctrl, {$scope:scope})

     //Or you could so this  well
     //elm.data('$ngControllerController', $controller(ctrl, {$scope:scope}) ); 
    }
  }
});
```

And in your view:-

```
  <div ng-controller="main">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    Nested:
          <div dyn-controller="item.name" ng-click="test()">{{name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zUdJwH?p=preview)**

Note that i have changed the position of ng-controller from the element that does ng-repeat, since ng-repeat (`1000`) has higher priority than ng-controller (`500`), ng-repeat's scope will prevail and you end up not repeating anything.

While looking at it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your second $controller proposal have inspired me for own solution

Answer (score 1):

Invested more couple hours into it, inspecting angular's sources etc.

The expression, given to `ng-controller`, is not being evaluated at all.

Here is best approach I've found:

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="main">
        Nested: {{name}}
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div ng-controller="nested" ng-init="init(item)">{{name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('main', function ($scope, $controller) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            name: 'Parent Controller',
            items: [
                {name: 'nested2'},
                {name: 'nested1'}
            ]
        });
    })
    .controller('nested', function ($scope, $controller) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            init: function (item) {
                $controller(item.name, {'$scope': $scope});
            }
        });
    })
    .controller('nested1', function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'test1';
    })
    .controller('nested2', function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'test2';
    });
```