# Using different controllers on the same directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have created a directive and service that combine to create a pop-up modal in our application. I can call the pop-up service which sets up a `scope` variable and causes a `modal` directive to become visible. The problem is I cannot figure out where the best place is to put the logic that I need for the individual instances of a pop-up modal.  Every modal will have a different view and therefore different logic to control the modal.

Is there a way to tell the directive to use a specific controller dynamically so I can control of code is ran while the different modals are visible to the user?

Here is my overlay Service which sets up the modal

```
.factory("Overlay", ["$rootScope", "$window", '$q', function ($rootScope, $window, $q) {
    var overlay = {};

    var el;
    var gears;
    var scope = {};

    var isActive = false;

    function _displayBackground() {
        $rootScope.overlayVisible = true;
    }

    function _hideBackground() {
        $rootScope.overlayVisible = false;
    }

    overlay.getScope = function(){
        return scope;
    }

    overlay.Gears = {
        show: function(msg, feedback){
            _displayBackground();

            var def1 = $q.deferred();
            var def2 = $q.deferred();

            $timeout(function(){
                def1.resolve({
                   result: {
                       Complete: true,
                       Success: true
                   }
                });
            }, Math.random() * 5000);

            $timeout(function(){
                def2.resolve({
                    result: {
                        Complete: true,
                        Success: false
                    }
                })
            }, Math.random() * 5000);

            feedback = [
                {
                    Label: 'Item 1',
                    Complete: false,
                    Promise: def1.promise
                }, {
                    Label: 'Item 2',
                    Complete: false,
                    Promise: def2.promise
                }
            ];

            scope.feedback = feedback;
            scope.message = msg;
            scope.url = '/partials/Common/gears.html';

            $rootScope.modalVisible = true;

        },
        hide: function(){
            _hideBackground();

            $rootScope.modalVisible = false;
        }
    };

    overlay.Alert = {
        show: function (title, content, hint, posCallback, btnText, negCallback) {
            _displayBackground();

            // el = angular.element(
        }
    }

    return overlay;

}])
```

And here is my modal directive

```
app.directive('skModal', function($window, Overlay){
   return {
       restrict:'EA',
       template: '<div ng-include="modal.url" onload="setPosition()"></div>',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           var top, left;

           scope.modal = {};

           scope.setPosition = function(){
               top = ($window.innerHeight - elem.outerHeight()) / 2;
               left = ($window.innerWidth - elem.outerWidth()) / 2;

               elem.css({ 'top': top, 'left': left });

           }

           scope.$watch(attrs.skModal, function(newVal){
               if(newVal) {
                   angular.extend(scope.modal, Overlay.getScope());
               }else{
                   elem.css({ 'top': -9999, 'left': -9999 });
                   scope.modal.url = '';
               }
           });

       }
   };
});
```

I basically link the scope I want to use from the Overlay service using `getScope` but I have no way to process the `Promise`s I wanted to use in this particular modal in order to show feedback of 1-many API calls.

Comment: Are you using angular ui bootstrap modal? There is a controller option you can set

Comment: No I actually am not... I wanted more flexibility so I just created my own, but I can try to mimic their implementation if possible

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you have done...Otherwise We will have to throw ideas in air... :) Just now i had posted one for kind of similar quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219866/angularjs-nested-controllers-from-variable/26220579#26220579 See if that is of any help

Comment: please show us your code snippet so we could understand your modal

Comment: I updated it with my current Service and Directive

Comment: Could I add another field onto my `scope` like `scope.ctrl` which is then used as the controller for the directive? The problem is the controller has already been instantiated at this point I believe.

Comment: @MattHintzke How do you use this directive? It is not a good idea to watch attributes. attr.$observe is used for that purpose

Comment: I am basically just trying to see when the showModal variable is true on the scope and then when it is, I show the modal